# Seq2Seq neural networks on very long sequences

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I have 1-dimensional signal which I would like to translate from integer electrical current to a DNA sequence (4-word alphabet) using seq2seq.

My input data is of the shape `[batch_size, 1000, 1]` and my output data `[batch_size, ? (~100), embedding_size]` where I encode each word in my base alphabet to a fixed-length vector of floats (between 4 and 64, longer seems to be better). I send this through a 2-layer, 64-unit LSTM encoder, and then apply Bahdanau Attention on a 2-layer, 64-unit LSTM decoder. Unfortunately, most of my outputs seem to be approximately 5 words in length.

I have read that seq2seq can handle "long" sentences ([Sutskever et al., page 7](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/5346-sequence-to-sequence-learning-with-neural-networks.pdf)) but as yet I am unable to replicate this success on what is a very small output vocabulary. Ideally I would like to increase my input length by a factor of 10 or 100 in the long run, if this is possible.

I am concerned that perhaps the encoded 'thought vector' simply is not storing enough information for the long sequence. Does anyone have experience / ideas on how to make a Seq2Seq model work with long sentences?